# Cauchy-Schwarz sanity check

Tags: inequality, soft-question, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Cauchy Schwarz say that $$\mid x_1y_1\mid +...+ \mid x_ny_n\mid \leq \sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}.$$  (This follows from the popular proof using AM-GM.)

This is Holder's inequality with conjugate pairs (2,2) if you like.  But it seems like everyone writes it as 
$$\mid x_1y_1+...+ x_ny_n\mid \leq \sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}.$$  The second one follows from the first one but the first one does not follow from the second, so why is the second way of writing it vastly more popular?

Comment: I have never seen CS stated in the first manner. Also, the first does follow from the second.

Comment: I agree with @copper.hat

Comment: Actually these two formulations are equivalent. Simply apply the second inequality to the vectors $(|x_1|, \dots , |x_n|)$ and $(|y_1|, \dots , |y_n|)$.

Comment: I've seen it formulated the first way. It is seemingly stronger, but as Crostul points out the second implies the first.

Comment: The 2nd is also a direct fit to its generalization to inner products on vector spaces $|u\cdot v| \le \|u\|\|v\|$, so it is not surprising to me that this form would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The second one follows from the proof with the quadratic function which is i think the most well known proof for C.S inequality. That's probably why it is preferred